# How to spot different electronic devices?

Tags: current, current-measurement, device, electron

Recently my university has changed traditional counter meters into intelligent ones where they cut the power for illegal devices. At first as the rules say, the illegal ones are those with power usage over 1kW but surprisingly it allows those devices to be used but it cuts power for rice cookers with as less as 400W power usage. My question is that if there is any trick that they used to detect rice cookers? And if so, how to bypass it? Does it have anything with current detection?

Comment: You want help with breaking the university rules? Just when I thought I'd seen it all...

Comment: @Dampmaskin Not really. As I mentioned, the school rules are not comprehensive. It says 1KW is the threshold but my rice cooker is 0.4KW. So I think maybe they should allow us to use it but it seems there is a trick they use to cheat on us with fake declaration of rules.

Comment: Right. They have cameras in every room and monitoring which devices you are connecting. Really, think about it a bit. And what exactly is the point of "fake declaration of rules"? These are to limit *you*, not them.

Comment: 'k' is for kilo, 'K' is for kelvin, 'W' is for watt. It's "1 kW". What university did you say you are in?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for your sarcasm. But there is a red light in the new counter meter that when the rice cook is on, it goes off and then the power cuts but when I use other devices like an electronic kettle, that red light doesnt show up.

Comment: Then your rice cooker is broken and consuming more than you think.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I dont think so. I asked other students and same thing happened to them. How can an electronic kettle with 3 times more power usage (1.35kW) use the power but a rice cooker cant?

Comment: @Transistor Cant you be more supportive than being sarcastic? It is 4am here in my side and I am kinda angry and upset at the same time so those mistakes happens when you are not in normal condition.

Comment: OK. Sorry for your troubles. Possibilities: (1) The overload monitor is set too low. (2) It's monitoring two apartments. (3) You have some other load drawing power that you have forgotten. (4) The rice cooker is faulty. (5) Find a multimeter and measure the resistance between the plug pins. It shouldn't be less than \$ \frac {P}{V^2} \$ where \$ P \$ is 1000 W and \$ V \$ is your mains voltage.

Comment: Lol might want to look into getting a variac to run your heater at a lower power or bring it up to temp slower

Comment: @sstobbe what is that?

Comment: Does it measure peak power? . If so then maybe the rice cooker is cycled on and off and temperature regulated so the average power is only 400W, in which case use a diode in series.

Comment: @lonesome its an autotransformer that allows you to adjust the line voltage into a device, http://www.orgchemboulder.com/Technique/Equipment/Images/Variac.jpg a restive heater will run at lower power with lower voltage

Answer (score 4):

It's much more likely your rice cooker has a significant in-rush current that trips the censor. (Pun intended) The 0.4kW value is once it has warmed up. Initially it probably gobbles up a couple of kW.

If you know how to wire stuff safely, or know someone that does, you may consider an [Inrush Current Limiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current_limiter). Or a suitable Uninterruptible Power Supply (UPS) might work.

**NOTE:** ICL probably will not work if the rice cooker contains smart electronics and is not just your simple electro-mechanical thermostat. When the power is applied by the electronics the ICL will drop the voltage to the whole cooker, and the electronics will likely reset. In that case you would need to install the ICL internal to the cooker in series with the heater coil.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65986/discussion-on-answer-by-trevor-how-to-spot-different-electronic-devices).